# Workplace law for dismissals and probation extensions

Tags: united-kingdom, contract-law, employment, england-and-wales

I posted a large amount of [background info here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/55637/a-comment-to-a-team-member-about-hygiene-has-caused-manager-to-lengthen-my-proba).

In short:

I began working for a company in the UK on the 1st June this year.  My 3 month probation was extended by one month.

The notice to extend my probation was given to me after 1st August (a couple of days after) and backdated to be within the 3 month period.  It was not signed.

On Friday of last week 2nd Oct, I made a mistake and acted unprofessionally towards another colleague relating to hygiene issues.

On 5th Oct I had a meeting with my manager, he congratulated me on passing my probation. At the end of the conversation I mentioned to him the incident.

Today (8th Oct) we had a "2-minute" informal meeting that turned into an hour long dismissal meeting.  I wasn't dismissed, I'm not sure if I could've been.

He mentioned that he has spoken to HR and they have said that it's legal for them to fire anyone within 2 years for anything whether you're on probation or not.

They will extend my probation by two months and have given me a final chance.

Are employers allowed to extend probation periods in this manner?  There's very little in my contract that touches on probation which leads me to believe it's intentional.

Is there a law that allows an employer to terminate a contract in the way described?

Can I be given a 'final warning' without any prior warnings, verbal or otherwise?  Does the company have to follow a standard procedure or is said procedure determined by the company?

Is the company within their right to extend the probation in this manner and more importantly, can they fire me on a whim?

[image: snippet from contract]
[image: another snippet]

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that policies regarding probation and termination in England are subject to laws, rather than to one's employment contract?

Comment: @feetwet, thank you, your help is much appreciated.  It was a typo for 'procedure', edited. With reference to the contract, it doesn't contain a great deal with respect to probation and/or dismissals.  I'll see if I can link the relevant parts

Comment: @feetwet, added a couple of snippets - someone has mentioned in the linked post that the inability to get along with co workers is a reason for dismissal, so it seems that I have no rights.

Comment: Looks like a standard "at-will" employment contract.  And the contract itself suggests the only legal restrictions would come from the Employment Rights Act.  Have you researched that to see if it bears on any of your questions?

Comment: I haven't, but I'm now going to. I didn't know it existed, thank you.